# In Keil MDK-ARM C++11 *default NAN value* for member and function's parameter generates strange errors

Tags: c++11, arm, nan, default-value, keil

Have you ever faced with yet another Keil's "*feature*" when next code

```
#include <cmath>
struct AB {
  float f=NAN;
  float foo(float a=NAN);
};
```

generates next build output:

> ```
> compiling main.cpp...
> ..\..\src\main.cpp(24): error:  #65: expected a ";"
>     float foo(float a=
> AN);
> ..\..\src\main.cpp(24): error:  #109: expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type
>         float foo(float a=NAN);
> ..\..\src\main.cpp(24): error:  #18: expected a ")"
>         float foo(float a=NAN);
> ..\..\src\main.cpp(24): error:  #18: expected a ")"
>         float foo(float a=NAN);
> ..\..\src\main.cpp(23): error:  #65: expected a ";"
>         float f=NAN;
> ..\..\src\main.cpp: 0 warnings, 5 errors`
> ```

For me it looks like bug. I have never met same nuisance in GCC and other compilers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**5 errors** in 2 rows. Fantastic. WTF? MDK-ARM cannot resolve `NAN`.
This could be fixed with next row:

```
#define __ESCAPE__(__x)  (__x)
```

Better make it for only this "*cool*" compiler:

```
#ifdef __CC_ARM
 #define __ESCAPE__(__x)  (__x)
#endif
```

---

Another solution (*not sure, but it could be compiler's extension*):

```
float f = 0f_7FC00000;
```